# resetting phone caused apk to stop working

Tags: android, apk, android-testing, android-install-apk

I have been working on testing in-app billing. Through the process, I learned that I needed to reset my device so as to wipe out my personal information or google would keep complainer about me not being able to purchase from myself. So indeed I reset the device and re-active gmail with my test account only. But now, my apk refuses to work. The second I click on the ic_launcher, the app login screen shows up but then the app crashes immediately. I have been at this all night/morning. Does anyone know why that might be happening? I am using an LG P-769 with android 4.1.2. The apk works on another device that I own.

The apk in question is a released apk creating using eclipse with proguard.

Comment: Do you have a logcat you could post?

Comment: @DigCamara No. For some reason my logCat is completely empty even with no filters.

Comment: Can you connect it to debug?

Comment: @DigCamara it's on verbose so I can catch everything coming out of the device. Nothing. Most likely there is something wrong there too. In the past all I had to do to rectify was unplug the usb and then reconnect. But that hasn't fixed it yet this time.

Comment: right. What I was trying to tell you (if you can debug) is to put a breakpoint on one of the lines which you know your app is reaching and step forward from then on. That way you'll see exactly where your app is crashing.

Comment: @DigCamara I didn't know I could debug a release apk with checkpoints. Is that what you are saying? How do I do that? Again, the apk works on my other device. It only crashes on my reset device, making it quite scary as I not only can't test in-app billing but I also am not sure what will happen on someone else's device. Before the reset, it works completely fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29493/discussion-between-digcamara-and-pouton-gerald)

Comment: Completely uninstall the app and do a re-install.  If the install fails, look at the logcat messages during the install.  If the launch fails, there will be logcat messages there too - there are logcat messages any time any app is launched, debug or even someone else's released app from the market.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is experiencing this seemingly rare bug:

As it turned out, resetting the device deleted all my contacts. As a result my app was throwing a NPE.